# TypeError: raw_parse() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sentence'

Tags: parsing, raw

**I tried this code below:**

```
from nltk.parse.corenlp import CoreNLPParser
sdp = nltk.parse.corenlp.CoreNLPDependencyParser
result = list(sdp.raw_parse(sentence))
```

**But I get this error**

> *TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_2712/97028793.py in 
> ----> 1 result = list(sdp.raw_parse(sentence)) TypeError: raw_parse() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sentence'*

**What should I do?**